# Faithfully flat map of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a faithfully flat  morphism of schemes. If necessary, one can put moderate mild assumptions on these as they are locally noetherian and the map is locally of finite type.

It occurred to me the necessity of a statement as follows: there exists  AFFINE open coverings $Y_i$ of $Y$ and $X_i$ of $X$ such that $f(X_i) \subseteq Y_i$ and $f|_{X_i}: X_i \to Y_i$ is faithfully flat. To obtain that, one should prove in particular that the maps $ f|_{X_i}$ are surjective. I wasn't able to ind such a statement in the literature neither to prove this. Is this even true?

Comment: Does this work? Take an affine open covering $Y=\bigcup_i U_i$, then we get faithfully flat maps $f_i:X_{i} \to U_i$ by pullback. For each $i$ we take an affine open cover $X_i = \bigcup_{j} V_{i,j}$, and since each $V_{i,j} \to X_i$ is an open immersion (hence flat), the map $Y_i:=V_{i,j} \to X_i \to U_i$ is flat. By construction, the map $\coprod_{j} V_{i,j} \to U_i$ is surjective and flat, and therefore faithfully flat. If $X_i$ is quasi-compact, then we can cover it by finitely many affine opens and then $Y_i$ is affine. I think this should handle the case when $f$ is fpqc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is "no". Depending on what you are trying to do exactly, you may want to require $f$ to be affine, or quasi-compact. If $f$ is affine, then for any affine open $Y'\subset Y$, the preimage $X'$ of $Y'$ in $X$ is an affine open subscheme of $X$ and the canonical map $X'\to Y'$ is faithfully flat. If $f$ is quasi-compact, then $X'$ can be covered by finitely many affine open subschemes of $X$, and the map from their disjoint union to $Y'$ is a faithfully flat morphism of affine schemes.

For a counterexample to the general statement, consider $Y=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$. For each closed point $y$ of $Y$, let $X_y$ be the localization of $Y$ at $y$. Call $X$ the disjoint union of the $X_y$ and $f$ the natural map $X \to Y$. Then, $f$ is faithfully flat, but there exist no nonempty affine open subschemes $Y'\subset Y$ and $X'\subset X$ such that $f(X')=Y'$ set-theoretically.

To see this, suppose given such $X',Y'$. Since $Y'$ contains infinitely many closed points of $Y$, we know that $X'$ must contain infinitely many of the $X_y$, so $X'$ is not quasi-compact and in particular not affine: we have a contradiction.

Comment: Great counterexample. I've got to admit I really have no clue about this kind of stuff for flat maps. Anyway, I did not well understand the quasicompact case: the disjoint union of affine opens of $X$ is not necessarily an open subset of $X$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just mentioned it because there are many quasi-compact but not affine morphisms, including some of the very common practical examples (e.g. $\mathbb P^n_S \to S$). So if it turns out to be enough for you to work with a finite disjoint union of opens on the source, you get a more general proof.